# How to create spreadsheet and install add-on or attach app script to the spreadsheet in google drive using php

Tags: php, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm creating a website that requires the functionality to create a spreadsheet in google drive and install a sheets add-on to the created spreadsheet on click of a button.

I'm able to create spreadsheet using the below code

```
// $client is the Google_Client() object with required properties
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$spreadsheet = new Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet([
    'properties' => [
        'title' => 'Spreadsheet Title'
    ]
]);

$spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheets->create($spreadsheet, [
    'fields' => 'spreadsheetId'
]);
```

May I know if there is a way to **install an add-on or attach app script** to that created spreadsheet through PHP?

If the above is not possible, is it possible to copy a spreadsheet that already has add-on installed in my google drive to user's google drive?

thanks,

Comment: Use the Apps Script API https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is important to distinguish between an Add-on and a bound script

- An Add-on ["is installed for a particular user after he or she chooses the add-on in the store"](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle). And "If two people collaborate on a document, and one of them uses an add-on, it is installed for the one user and enabled for the document."

> This means that if you use an Add-on and share your document with
>   other users, those users will be able to use the Add-on on the
>   specific document you share with them. However, if you make a copy of
>   this document to a user's drive, and this copy will be only used by
>   the user, but not by you - the user can use the Add-on, unless he
>   manually installs it.

- A bound script is attached to a document. If you make a copy from
  your drive to the user's drive - the document will be copied
  including the bound script.

**To copy file including bound script to user's drive, you can create a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with the content**

```
function doGet() {
  DriveApp.getFileById('INSERT ID OF THE FILE ON YOUR DRIVE').makeCopy();
}
```

**and deploy it as "User accessing the web app" and "Who has access to the app" -> "Anyone"**
[image]

> Keep in mind that this works only if you assign to the file on on your
>   drive viewing permissions, i.e. you need to share the file with your
>   domain or public users - depending on your intentions. In the last
>   step you copy the URL of the Web App and set-up your Website in such a
>   way that you redirect to the Web App URL, when a user clicks a button.

- Instead of copying a file with an Apps Script, you can also attach posteriourly a script to any created or existing document. For this, you can use the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest), as proposed by Diego. You need to [create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) an empty script project, following the sample in the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/php), but make sure to specify the `parentId` of the file to which you want to bind the script. Subsequently, [update](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent) the content of the file with a [file.source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/File)

Comment: Hi, @ziganotschka thank you for your answer, it works perfectly for my requirement. but for the following error `User has not enabled the Apps Script API. Enable it by visiting https://script.google.com/home/usersettings then retry.`. Is there a way to enable it while getting authorization or some other way to enable programmatically for the user?

Comment: A solution I can think of implies using a service account with impersonation that acts on behalf of the user. This is however only possible for usrs of your domain.

Comment: Could you send me any link or any resource explaining this topic more? I quiet don't understand the implementation.

Comment: Here is the official google documentaion: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts Basically, you can enable domain-wide delegation in your admin console and then you can write a script that runs a function through a service account that impersonates a domain-user - e.g. acts, as if it were the domain user and accesses his data. Since the script can be run by you, the user does not need to enable the script API - only you.